# Images not centering on mobile

Tags: css

Look at this [page](https://wizard4socialmedia.com/about)

There are 3 images on the right. When I look at my site with a mobile device, those 3 images stay there instead of centering in the middle, and so they make the page overflow/have a left-right scroll.

Any ideas on how I can fix it so that the images get centered when the page is viewed on mobile?

Thank you

Comment: where do you want them to be? between the texts?

Comment: Below the texts would be fine.

Comment: Overflow is not because of those 3 images. It because of the logo img in the header which has the class `brand`

Answer (score 1):

### Use a CSS media Query

The code used in the example you gave is

```
@media (max-width: 600px)
.about-us-images {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

The `@media (max-width: 600px)` part is telling the page to only apply those styles when a page width is 600px or less.

### Adjust it to Your Preferences

You can adjust that to any size you wish or use the reverse to style any page that is 600px or wider using:  `@media (min-width: 600px)`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this—

```
@media (max-width:600px) {
    .about-us-text,
    .about-us-images { width:100% } 
}
```

Just add a class to the images div, and change the breakpoint as you wish. Looks like this now—
[image]

Comment: Okay, this makes sense and should work, but it's not. I added the class and the css, but it's not working.

Comment: I played with this a little bit, and I managed to fix it. Thank you for the idea :)

Comment: Good to hear! What did you have to do finally?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I had to do.

```
@media (max-width:600px) {
    .about-us-text {
        float: none !important;
        width:100% !important;
    } 
}

@media (max-width:600px) {
    .about-us-images {
        width: 100% !important;
    } 
}
```

That did it.